# Weird behavior of has_one after upgrade to Rails 4.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2, has-one

I have two models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group, dependent: :destroy

  validates :login, presence: true

  before_create :add_group

  private

  def add_group
    create_group(name: login)
  end
end
```

and

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
end
```

When I try to create user, I get `SystemStackError: stack level too deep`.
So I changed add_group callback like this:

```
def add_group
  create_group(name: login) unless group
end
```

Now, it saves the user and properly set group_id, but create also second empty record of User without validation.
SQL:

```
>> u = User.create!(login: "foo")
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (2.2ms)  INSERT INTO "groups" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "foo"], ["created_at", "2016-04-06 10:09:52.981954"], ["updated_at", "2016-04-06 10:09:52.981954"]]
  Group Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1453]]
  SQL (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("login", "created_at", "updated_at", "group_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["login", "foo"], ["created_at", "2016-04-06 10:09:52.923926"], ["updated_at", "2016-04-06 10:09:52.923926"], ["group_id", 1453]]
  SQL (1.4ms)  INSERT INTO "users" DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING "id"
   (9.1ms)  COMMIT
```

The last INSERT INTO users table is odd.
I can't figure out why this happens...

I found two solutions:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, autosave: false
  ##OR##
  has_one :usr, class_name: "User"

  # has_one :user, class_name: "User" works weird too
end
```

but it doesn't convince me.

What can be wrong? at Rails 4.0 everything works well.

**UPDATE 1**

ok, I found 2 other solutions:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group, dependent: :destroy

  validates :login, presence: true

  before_create :add_group

  private

  def add_group
    self.group = Group.create(name: login)
    # OR #
    assign_attributes(group: Group.create(name: login))
  end
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
end
```

but still I don't understand why it's behave so strange... especially this extra empty record and fix by `has_one :usr, class_name: "User"`

Comment: have you tried changing before_create :add_group, to after_create ?

Comment: yes, but then I have another problem: create_group in after_create fires after_update callbacks, what complicates many things

Comment: And I can't create user if creating group fails

Answer (score 0):

You should only **build** your group and let AR persist it for you:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group, dependent: :destroy

  validates :login, presence: true

  before_create :add_group

  private

  def add_group
    build_group(name: login)
  end
end
```

When calling `create_group`, it will relaunch the AR validations again, and therefore relaunching your `before_create` hook.

Comment: I try to, but it doesn't save the group, although it's valid (even with belongs_to :group, autosave: true)

Comment: And I think you mean `build_group(name: login)` because the `group` at this moment is `nil` :)

Comment: Absolutely, thanks! I'll edit my answer. As for why it's not working...`@user.save!` should actually persist it. Could you maybe add a `binding.pry` in the `add_group` callback and try to launch the code to see what happens?

Comment: It builds properly group, and group has correct reference to user, but still doesn't save the group

Answer (score 0):

the answer is here: `autosave: false`

That means that when you are adding a group to the user, rails assigns de group_id to the user (belongs_to) so tries to save de object again, I suppose that because you are still in the create behaviour, that #save fires the after_create again and there you get the stack level too deep.

use `group.create(name: login)` instead.

Comment: I can understand the stack level too deep, but why in second version (with unless) it creates second empty object without validation?

Comment: `group.create(name: login)` is eql to `nil.create(name: login)` - we can do this like this `build_group(name: login).save`, but it gives us the same result like `create_group`, `group = Group.create()` etc